# How to split bracketed list in python with regex'?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, split, python-2.x

I am trying to use the re module in python to split a string that represents a list. The list is identified by brackets.

Input:

```
"[1]first[2]second[3]third" ... etc
```

Desired output:

```
['first', 'second', 'third',...]
```

My current code is as follows:

```
out = re.split('\[(.*?)\]', thelist)
```

It returns the following, but how do I get the desired?

```
['', '1', 'first', '2', "second", '3', 'third',...]
```

Comment: What if the list elements contain `[number]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to match numbers enclosed with `[...]` and get rid of the empty elements with:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\[\d+\]')
test_str = "[1]first[2]second[3]third"
print([x for x in p.split(test_str) if x])
# => ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/5VXR1E)

To get the output *with* the numbers in ***Python 3*** you can use

```py
import re
test_str = "[1]first[2]second[3]third"
print( re.split(r'(?!^)(?=\[\d+])', test_str) )
```

See [this **Python 3** demo](https://ideone.com/04xsCe).

Your code returned the captured texts since [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) returns all captures as separate elements in the resulting array.

> If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches at the start of the string, the result will start with an empty string.

Also, to get rid of just the first empty element, you may use

```
res = p.split(test_str)
if not res[0]:
    del res[0]
```

Comment: what if the list had no brackets and looked something like:
    1.sdjdjdj2.sdjsdjjsd3.sdjdjds54.sdjsd

There can be numbers before the list number?

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that it takes away the 54. when it should just be taking away the 4. in the last element of the list. 
Another example 1.kk2.y63.tt -> [kk,y6,tt] and not [kk,y,tt]

Comment: How long are the lists? What are their exact boundaries? What about float values inside?There are too many variables here. Try [`p = re.compile(r'\d\.')`](http://ideone.com/PLUGjM).

Answer (score 1):

Use out[2::2].  This takes every entry from the third to the end, but taking only every second entry.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always the same and you don't have brackets in the words  then use findall and get the strings after each closing bracket:

```
s = "[1]first[2]second[3]third"

import re

print(re.findall("\](\w+)" ,s))
['first', 'second', 'third']
```

To handle spaces etc.. you can use a character set:

```
s = "[1]first foo[2]second[3]third"

import re

print(re.findall("\]([\w\s]+)", s))
['first foo', 'second', 'third']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple regex if your string looks the way you described:

```
re.findall(r'[a-z]+', s)
```

[**`findall`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will return a list for you, so no need for `split`

And the output:

```
['first', 'second', 'third']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I used a lookahead to find a match with |$ to find the last sentence

print(".+? is the ungreedy character match")
print("(?=\[\d{2}\]) is the lookforward character match")
pattern="\[\d{2}\].+?(?=\[\d{2}\]|$)"
matches=re.findall(pattern,txt)
for match in matches:
    print("output",match)
output:

output [01] Final Step - Protonica 
output [02] Liquid Frequencies (Liquid Soul Mix) - Liquid Soul 
output [03] Global Illumination - Liquid Soul 
output [04] Devotion - Liquid Soul 
output [05] Black Rock City - Quantize 
output [06] Plazza Del Trripy - Andromeda 
output [07] Private Guide - Suntree 
output [08] Stereo Gun - Vibrasphere 
output [09] The Cycle - Ritree 
output [10] Atmonizer - Andromed
```